# WEP QOS_DATA vs DATA decryption - difference?

Tags: brute-force, decryption, wep

I recently played a bit with my hardware pocket size IV WEP sniffer.
It's a 5v tool that i use in my lab when bored:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJyRaWrnbJg

In my tests i figured out one of my MIFI routers is sending data packets as QOS_DATA, while the other one is sending DATA.

I wrote a bruteforcer years ago for WEP, that does the magic by generating wordlist on the fly and doing the decryption ( later ).

I noticed however that it doesn't work on QOS_DATA packets, even though they are no different than DATA but prefixed with 2 bytes header.

So i added 2 bytes forward for QOS_DATA frames - in order to position for the IV, DATA and ICV properly.

And went with the testing, where

**a)** MIFI is 64bit encrypted (24b for IV, 40b for KEY: ola13) sending *QOS*

**b)** MIFI is 64bit encrypted (24b for IV, 40b for KEY: MYKEY) sending *DATA*

And just for the sake of clarity, i add snapshots from WireShark too.

**TEST A** - Cracking WEP QOS

[image]

Unfortunately the cracker does not work even though KEY has been provided.

```
WEPCracker (c) Codemaster 2015
Using userkey: ola13
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 121 0/248

IV: 32 0E 32 

DATA: 9B 0C 9E 85 D0 4E 45 3A C1 0A 4A 70 6A 39 C1 76 0E D8 24 9C A6 28 DF A5 A0 2D D9 1B F5 B5 6D 50 1F B8 06 86 FA 5D 5C 14 FC FE 23 66 2A 30 79 A9 D0 32 8E BF 3D 7A 7D 87 36 5A 96 F7 5F 98 F7 C9 F3 93 4B 69 22 06 37 93 92 A4 B1 02 29 88 4D 81 1C F0 76 E1 32 63 81 

ICV: 4D D7 6D 5E 
CRC Check: 8a6d3411 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
Not found, tried with key ola13
```

**TEST B** - Cracking WEP DATA

[image]

For DATA it works without a problem.

```
WEPCracker (c) Codemaster 2015
Using userkey: MYKEY
- Found Data packet for BSSID 00:23:cd:1f:73:b0, Length 108 0/5

IV: CE A2 6F 

DATA: FC 98 7D DD CA 59 74 19 2A A5 79 B6 20 BC 61 89 75 E3 31 EC 27 E8 2D 6D 28 3E 87 1B 25 41 0A A5 F5 21 CB 11 D2 57 FF 09 69 48 6C 41 69 37 87 98 30 F9 A2 34 38 FC 5C 7E F3 FB DB 03 6B 68 25 3A CA C0 03 07 ED AF 08 8C 23 25 28 91 

ICV: CD 24 FF 64 

CRC Check: 4c627c0d / 4c627c0d [MYKEY]
[!] Potential KEY found (MYKEY)
```

**Additional thing i noted for QOS**

Whatever the packet, it seems i get always the same CRC32 calculated *1cdf4421*

*QOS CRC32 DUMP ON ALL PACKETS*

```
WEPCracker (c) Codemaster 2015
Using userkey: ola13
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 121 0/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 1/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 2/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 3/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 4/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 5/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 6/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 7/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 8/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 9/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 10/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 11/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 12/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 13/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 14/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 15/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 16/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 17/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 18/248
- Found Data packet for BSSID f8:01:13:c9:15:25, Length 106 19/248
CRC Check: 203ad131 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 2ea421c8 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 2a4cbe7f / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: ba9ff515 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: e9ad711c / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: eac88ae5 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 3b8b1585 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 5db4c3de / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 5e729189 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 952ee95f / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: fbb93926 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: b343645f / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 32e27718 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 57d1cb67 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 7b0aa646 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: d88dbc28 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: a10c8c1b / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 2dcd9381 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 26e6c087 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: ec9e9cae / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: c5c4ae8b / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
CRC Check: 974c8ff6 / 1cdf4421 [ola13]
```

*DATA CRC32 DUMP ON ALL PACKETS*

```
 WEPCracker (c) Codemaster 2015
Using userkey: MYKEY
- Found Data packet for BSSID 00:23:cd:1f:73:b0, Length 108 0/5
- Found Data packet for BSSID 00:23:cd:1f:73:b0, Length 86 1/5
- Found Data packet for BSSID 00:23:cd:1f:73:b0, Length 86 2/5
- Found Data packet for BSSID 00:23:cd:1f:73:b0, Length 86 3/5
- Found Data packet for BSSID 00:23:cd:1f:73:b0, Length 86 4/5
Total number of Words: 11881376
CRC Check: 4c627c0d / 4c627c0d [MYKEY]
CRC Check: db260e81 / db260e81 [MYKEY]
CRC Check: db260e81 / db260e81 [MYKEY]
CRC Check: db260e81 / db260e81 [MYKEY]
CRC Check: db260e81 / db260e81 [MYKEY]
```

**DECRYPTION PROCESS**

Let me also explain the process of encryption.

**KEY** = WEP passphrase (either *ola13* or *MYKEY* as seen above)

**IV** = Initialisation Vector

**ICV** = Integrity Check Value

1. I Get **[IV][DATA][ICV]** out of the QOS or DATA WEP encrypted packet
2. I Run RC4 on the **[DATA][ICV]** with **[IV][KEY]**
3. From that moment i have a decrypted **[DATA][ICV]**
4. I Run CRC32 on **[DATA]**
5. I Compare the CRC32 output with decrypted **[ICV]**
6. If they match, the **[KEY]** is a hit
7. If they don't match, they **[KEY]** is wrong

Is there any difference in decrypting WEP Protected QOS and DATA or i am missing some bit here..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fault on not taking into consideration some drivers do not provide Radiotap header so no FCS was counted.